# Can I create a simple onclick event using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
<html>
     <body>

     <button onclick = "Link()">click here</button>

     <script>
     function Link() {
     anchor.href = "C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/Folder/Page.html";
     }

     </script>

     </body>

     </html>
```

Would just like to be able to link to a local folder on my computer using html and JavaScript.

Comment: How are you serving the above code? Is it local too or is it coming via an http type request e.g. from an external server?

Comment: It is local, yes.

Comment: How is anchor defined in your code?